# Rotating symbols while keeping track of the anchor

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, svg, rotation

I've just started testing out the new [Symbol feature](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Symbols) that was added in Google Maps API v3.9. I want to have multiple triangle-like symbols on the map, and I want to be able to rotate them programatically. What I previously had was a set of png images where each one was a copy of the last one, just rotated 10 degrees (MyIcon_0, MyIcon_10, ... , MyIcon350). I would then just draw the image that was closest to the rotation angle I wanted.

Using the new symbol feature instead seemed like a much easier way, that gave full control over both rotation and colors programatically.

Using the SVG path notation, I defined a simple triangle, and stuck it on a Marker like this:

```
var markerOptions = {
   icon: {
        path: "M 0 5 L 20 5 L 10 40 z",
        rotation: rotationAngle,
        anchor: [something]
    },
    position: position
};

var marker = new Marker(markerOptions);
```

This works fine as long as the "rotationAngle" is set to 0, because I then know what the anchor will have to be in order to put the symbol on the correct location in the map. I want the anchor to always be at the "acute angled corner" of the triangle.

The problem occurs when I have another rotation angle. The symbol is drawn on a rectangular canvas, and the dimensions of the canvas seems to be automatically calculated to best fit the shape inside. When you rotate a symbol like this triangle, you will have a canvas that has different dimensions based on the rotation, and this makes it hard to position the symbol correctly on the map, as the anchor seems to be set relatively to the canvas dimensions.

If I could only be able to control the size of the actual canvas I would be able to draw the symbol so that the anchor is always in the center of the canvas, and then it would be possible to set a constant anchor. Is this somehow possible? I was thinking about the possibility of drawing an invisible circle around the shape, that would make sure to keep the canvas size constant, but I am not too familiar with the SVG path notation, and I do not know if this is possible to achieve.

Will be thankful for any constructive feedback on this matter.

Comment: Vector paths on a polyline must fall within a 22x22px square so if your invisible circle radius is <= 11px and anchor 11,11 it should rotate round centre of circle

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I am not using polylines, but markers. I tried using a very small version of my symbol (smaller than 22x22px), to see if that would make all the symbols size 22x22px, but still the canvas was set just big enough to fit the symbol. (12x8px, 15x14px, etc.. based on the rotation). That was without a surrounding invisible circle, because I still don't know if it is possible to insert an invisible circle within the same symbol as my visible triangle. Do you know if it is possible to set multiple symbols on the same canvas? (one for my triangle, one for an invisible circle)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Centering google maps SymbolPath on LatLon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28254425/centering-google-maps-symbolpath-on-latlon)

Answer (score 5):

Set your anchor to (10, 20).

```
var icon = {
        path: "M 0 5 L 20 5 L 10 40 z",
        scale: 1,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#009933',
        fillOpacity: 0.001,
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 20)
    };
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j7rc3qvm/4/)

working code snippet:

```js
var map;
var angle = 0;
var marker;
var icon = {
  path: "M 0 5 L 20 5 L 10 40 z",
  scale: 1,
  strokeWeight: 2,
  fillColor: '#009933',
  fillOpacity: 0.001,
  anchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 20)
};

function init() {
  var startLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(50.124462, -5.539994);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: startLatLng,
    zoom: 12
  });

  var ptMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(50.124462, -5.539994),
    map: map,
    icon: {
      url: "https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/markers2/measle.png",
      size: new google.maps.Size(7, 7),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(4, 4)
    }
  });
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(50.124462, -5.539994),
    icon: icon
  });
  marker.setMap(map);
  var circleMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(50.124462, -5.539994),
    map: map,
    icon: {
      path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
      scale: 24,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: '#009933',
      fillOpacity: 0.001,
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0)
    }
  });

  setInterval(function() {
    angle += 30;
    icon.rotation = angle;
    marker.setIcon(icon);
  }, 1000);

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map-canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```