# Centering google maps SymbolPath on LatLon

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to get the google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW to put the center of the icon at the LatLng position. It seems to be putting the point of the arrow there.

I have tried to experiment with the anchor but to no avail.

Here is my example code:

```
    var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
position: new google.maps.LatLng(50.124462, -5.539994),
icon: {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
        scale: 8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#009933',
        fillOpacity: 1,
        rotation: 210,
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0)
      },
});
marker.setMap(map);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For that symbol, use an anchor of (0,2.6)

[fiddle demonstrating that at various rotations](http://jsfiddle.net/j7rc3qvm/3/)

Simplest way to find experimentally is remove the rotation, then play with the anchor to see where it goes.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(50.124462, -5.539994),
    icon: {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
        scale: 8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#009933',
        fillOpacity: 1,
        rotation: 210,
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(0,2.6)
    },
});
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j7rc3qvm/1/)

working code snippet:

```js
var map;

function init() {
  var startLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(50.124462, -5.539994);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: startLatLng,
    zoom: 12
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(50.124462, -5.539994),
    map: map
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(50.124462, -5.539994),
    icon: {
      path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
      scale: 8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: '#009933',
      fillOpacity: 1,
      rotation: 210,
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 2.6)
    },
  });
  marker.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map-canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```