# Google maps API twisting marker

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to find a how to get the Google maps marker (it's an arrow) twisting. I know the direction in which the marker has to twist (an angle from 0 to 360°), but can't find anything about it on the internet.

Does anyone know how I need to do it? I know Google maps does it on phones like this:

[image: Google Maps Icon]

Comment: Are you asking how to make the arrow rotate based on which direction you're supposed to be traveling?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rotating symbols while keeping track of the anchor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472637/rotating-symbols-while-keeping-track-of-the-anchor)

Answer (score 3):

When you set the icon on the map, you can use the `rotation` property on the `google.maps.Symbol` object.  See here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Symbol

Furthermore, you can use `google.maps.spherical.computeHeading()` if you need to determine the value for the `rotation` property. See here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical

Example:

```
var heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(fromLatLng, toLatLng);

marker.setIcon({    
    scale: 6,
    rotation: heading
});
```